# Unset trainable attributes for parameters in lasagne / nolearn neural networks

Tags: python, lasagne, nolearn

I'm implementing a convolutional neural network using lasagne nolearn.

I'd like to fix some parameters that prelearned.
How can I set some layers untrainable?

Actually, though I removed 'trainable' attribute of some layers,
the number shown in the layer information before fitting, namely, such as

Neural Network with *** learnable parameters                                                never change.

Besides, I'm afraid that the greeting function 
in 'handers.py'

```
def _get_greeting(nn):
    shapes = [param.get_value().shape for param in
              nn.get_all_params() if param]
```

should be

```
nn.get_all_params(trainable=True) if param]
```

but I'm not sure how it affect on training.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass only a set of your layers into your updates. I've just been implementing something similar, and I've just simply removed some parameters from the parameter list:

`params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)` and then `params = params[-4:]`
This selects the last 4 layers in my network, leaving the first layers untrained. This can be generalised by picking out the layer that you want stop training on using something like:
`lasagne.layers.get_all_layers` and then filtering out which layers (parameters) to be trained.